# After filtering (search table), doesn't work item selection (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

---

```
import UIKit

let country = ["Argentina", "Australia", "Belgium", "Brazil", "Colombia", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Denmark", "Egypt", "England", "France", "Germany", "Iceland", "Iran", "Japan", "Mexico", "Morocco", "Nigeria", "Panama", "Peru", "Poland", "Portugal", "Republic of Korea", "Russia", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Tunis", "Uruguay"]

let country2 = ["Argentina2", "Australia2", "Belgium2", "Brazil2", "Colombia2", "Costa Rica2", "Croatia2", "Denmark2", "Egypt2", "England2", "France2", "Germany2", "Iceland2", "Iran2", "Japan2", "Mexico2", "Morocco2", "Nigeria2", "Panama2", "Peru2", "Poland2", "Portugal2", "Republic of Korea2", "Russia2", "Saudi Arabia2", "Senegal2", "Serbia2", "Spain2", "Sweden2", "Switzerland2", "Tunis2", "Uruguay2"]

let country3 = ["Argentina3", "Australia3", "Belgium3", "Brazil3", "Colombia3", "Costa Rica3", "Croatia3", "Denmark3", "Egypt3", "England3", "France3", "Germany3", "Iceland3", "Iran3", "Japan3", "Mexico3", "Morocco3", "Nigeria3", "Panama3", "Peru3", "Poland3", "Portugal3", "Republic of Korea3", "Russia3", "Saudi Arabia3", "Senegal3", "Serbia3", "Spain3", "Sweden3", "Switzerland3", "Tunis3", "Uruguay3"]

var myIndex = 0

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filteredArray = country.filter({$0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
        if searchText == "" {
            filteredArray = country
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    var filteredArray = [String]()
    var searchController = UISearchController()
    var searchBar = UISearchBar()
    var resultController = UITableViewController()
    let country = ["Argentina", "Australia", "Belgium", "Brazil", "Colombia", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Denmark", "Egypt", "England", "France", "Germany", "Iceland", "Iran", "Japan", "Mexico", "Morocco", "Nigeria", "Panama", "Peru", "Poland", "Portugal", "Republic of Korea", "Russia", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Tunis", "Uruguay"]


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        filteredArray = country
        searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 50)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
        self.searchBar.delegate = self
        definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.filteredArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "seque", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "seque" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let viewController: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
                viewController.myIndex = indexPath
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Please elaborate item selection not working. Are you talking about `didSelectRowAt` ?

Comment: @DmitryGaponenko use [imgur](https://imgur.com/) if you want to share any image. Your link is asking for login.

Comment: @DmitryGaponenko In `didSelectRowAt:` method you're not checking the `if tableView == self.tableView` like you're doing in every where to distinguish the `self.country` and `self.filteredArray`. So everytime you're clicking on first row it is showing the first `country` data. Are you getting what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

There are some problem in your code:

1. In `cellForRow` you are dequeuing your Table View, Not the tableView given by delegate method. `self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:` Here do not use `self`.
2. You are using `resultController` which does not have any prototype cell to display data. Here your app will crash.
3. I do not understand what you have done in `prepareForSegue`
4. Do not use any global variable. If you want to use `myIndex`, make a property in destinationVC and pass it `prepareForSegue`.
5. You are displaying filteredArray on table view and on selection getting value from `country` array, that's why you are getting wrong value.

What I found is, you do not need a `SearchViewController` because you are using a single View controller to display your filtered data.

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filteredArray = country.filter({$0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
    if searchText == "" {
        filteredArray = country
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

var filteredArray = [String]()
var searchController = UISearchController()
var searchBar = UISearchBar()
var resultController = UITableViewController()
let country = ["Argentina", "Australia", "Belgium", "Brazil", "Colombia", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Denmark", "Egypt", "England", "France", "Germany", "Iceland", "Iran", "Japan", "Mexico", "Morocco", "Nigeria", "Panama", "Peru", "Poland", "Portugal", "Republic of Korea", "Russia", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Tunis", "Uruguay"]


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    filteredArray = country
    searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 50)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
    self.searchBar.delegate = self
    definesPresentationContext = true
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.filteredArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "seque", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "seque" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let viewController: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
            let newIndex: Int = country.index(of: filteredArray[indexPath.row])!

            viewController.myIndex = newIndex

        }
    }
}
}
```

Please let me know if this worked.

**EDIT**

Your class `ViewController` should look like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView3: UIImageView!

var myIndex: Int!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myImageView.image = UIImage(named: country[myIndex])
    myImageView2.image = UIImage(named:country2[myIndex])
    myImageView3.image = UIImage(named: country3[myIndex])
}
// Other methods
}
```

Comment: This is out of context. Try it yourself. For more details please [Move to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170129/discussion-on-answer-by-chanchal-chauhan-after-filtering-search-table-doesnt)